# Cannot find an overload for "SoftwareIdentity"

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0, azure-powershell

I'd like to use functionality from the latest Azure Powershell library but I'm struggling to install it.  This is on an AWS x64 Windows 2012 R2 Standard server.

I get the following error

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> Install-Module -Name AzureAD
WARNING: Cannot find an overload for "SoftwareIdentity" and the argument count: "17".
PackageManagement\Install-Package : No match was found for the specified search criteria and module name 'AzureAD'.
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PowerShellGet\PSModule.psm1:1809 char:21
+             $null = PackageManagement\Install-Package @PSBoundParameters
+                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Microsoft.Power....InstallPackage:InstallPackage) [Install-Package], Ex
   ception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoMatchFoundForCriteria,Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.InstallPackage
```

This is with PSVersion = 4.0

Get-Module shows: 3.1.0.0 Microsoft.PowerShell.Management, 3.1.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility Script, 1.1.1.0 PackageManagement Script, 1.1.2.0 PowerShellGet

Get-PSRepository shows PSGallery Untrusted https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2/

Do you have any pointers to help troubleshoot / fix please?
Thanks

Comment: Wasn't it `Install-Package` for PS4? Also, you might want to upgrade to PS5...

Comment: `PS C:\Users\Administrator> Install-Package AzureAD
WARNING: Cannot find an overload for "SoftwareIdentity" and the argument count: "17".
Install-Package : No match was found for the specified search criteria and package name 'AzureAD'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package AzureAD
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Microsoft.Power....InstallPackage:InstallPackage) [Install-Package], Ex
   ception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoMatchFoundForCriteria,Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.InstallPackage`

Comment: Are you able to find the module using `Find-Module AzureAD`, and then pipe that to `Install-Module`?

Comment: Still the same error Cannot find an overload....
`PS C:\Users\Administrator> Find-Module AzureAD
WARNING: Cannot find an overload for "SoftwareIdentity" and the argument count: "17".
PackageManagement\Find-Package : No match was found for the specified search criteria and module name 'AzureAD'.
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PowerShellGet\PSModule.psm1:1397 char:3......[truncated]`

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I installed Win8.1AndW2K12R2-KB3134758-x64.msu from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50395
Now `Get-Module` returns nothing and the first time I tried `Install-Module -Name AzureAD` it moaned about the -Name parameter.  Second time (which I'm assuming means I'm imagining the first time) it worked.  Now to see if I can add a user to an Azure AD group using the latest OpenICF connector scripts.